# Setting up stylelint with Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, stylelint

I'm trying to hook up https://github.com/kungfusheep/SublimeLinter-contrib-stylelint to sublime... I've used SublimeLinter with the eslint and csslint addons before and they've worked perfectly.

After installing the stylelint everything seems to be running smoothly, only that sublime shows no linting errors even thought there are many. I have the stylelint package installed both -g and in my project. No errors or anything in sublime.

I'm thinking it could be that it doesn't find the config file of my project, although I think it's unlikely since I'm using a react-boilerplate as my starter project. But is there any way to see if the plugin has detected the config file?

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You're suspicions would be correct I think in that Sublime Text 3 can't find your stylelint config, have a read of this issue and see if the workarounds in that will help you out https://github.com/kungfusheep/SublimeLinter-contrib-stylelint/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I finally realized that sublime won't parse the file without an extension. On your stylelintrc you need to add the .json extension, so it should look like this:

.stylelintrc.json

Also ensure that you do not have any errors in your .stylelintrc.json file or Sublime will throw an error and just won't work. Hope this helps.